# Android AVD hangs on start-up when targeting Android 4.3

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Using Eclipse I've been running various of the pre-made AVD devices without problem and also a small AVD of my own settings (user created).

There is a bug where apps running in AVDs targeting Android 4.4 don't receive the orientation change when you use Ctrl-F12 to rotate the AVD. Because of this I used the Eclipse Andoid SDK Manager and installed Android 4.3 (except the samples) and also installed all the level 18 Android SDK build Tools. I then stopped and started Eclipse.

I then edited the AVD I had created using the Eclipse Android AVD to target Android 4.3. When I start the AVD it just hangs at the animated Android loading screen. I left it there for over an hour, it still did not load. I then changed it back to Android 4.4 and it ran ok. Changing back to 4.3 and it hung again.

There is nothing in console or logcat to help. What am I doing wrong?

[image: SDK Manager]

[image: AVD Manager]

Comment: delete that avd and try starting a new avd with the same configurations. I think that is the most simplest solution..

Comment: I recommend always creating NEW AVD per API level and in general for any configuration as the emulator will install/configure stuff on first launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had decided to try deleting the AVD and setting it back up again before noticing the comments above. It did the trick :)